# Closing a MenuStrip programmatically

Tags: c#, windows, forms, menustrip

I have a MenuStrip that I have added to a form, and in one of the dropdown menus in it, I have a text box. When I hit enter on the textbox, I want a function to run, then the drop down menu to close. I know how to get the enter part done, but I have no idea how to close the MenuStrip dropdown menu.

Comment: Please do not put tags (C#) into the title. Leave them in the tags.

Comment: Sorry about that, won't happen again.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Call the Owner's Hide() method.  For example:

```
    private void toolStripTextBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) {
        if (e.KeyData == Keys.Enter) {
            e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
            toolStripTextBox1.Owner.Hide();
        }
    }
```

Comment: What if it's a submenu of another menu? How do I go up the chain of submenus to get to the very root of the menu? I tried Owner.Owner but that's undefined and Owner.Parent results in an Exception of "Parent not set".

Comment: Just call the HideDropDown() method of the particular menu item you want to hide.

Answer (score 3):

You can try this (worked for me)

`for(int x = 0; x < menu.Items.Count; x++)`
    `((System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripDropDownItem)menu.Items[x]).HideDropDown();`

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question, but I ran into the same issue and figured out the solution, so for others out there:

You need to call the `HideDropDown()` method of the main menu item, regardless of how nested your textbox (or other control) is.

For instance, let's say you have a tool strip with `File`, `Edit`, `Help`. On the `Edit` menu, you have your textbox nested somewhere:

EditMenuItem
-> FindMenuItem
   -> SearchTextBoxHere

You would call the Edit menu's `HideDropDown()` method on your textbox's keydown event:

```
EditMenuItem.HideDropDown();
```